# set frame viewcontrollers view in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm trying to change the frame of VC does not work. this is my code:

```
AZControlViewController *vc = [[AZControlViewController alloc] init];
vc.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 195, 320, 500);
self.vcMaster = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease];
```

`AZControlViewControlleris` is a `UITableViewController`.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See with a breakpoint or a NSLog this `tableView` property of `vc`. It should be `nil`. This happens because the view's components of the view controller will only be initilized after the view controller was presented.

To change the frame of your tableView properly, inside the `AZControlViewController.m`, implement the method above and change the frame as you want.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 195, 320, 500);
}
```

If you still want to set this frame from a outside class, create a property to store the frame you want, and then assign this frame to the tableView's frame.

In `AZControlViewController.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect tableViewFrame;
```

In `AZControlViewController.m`:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.frame = self.tableViewFrame;
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
AZControlViewController *vc = [[AZControlViewController alloc] init];
vc.tableViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 195, 320, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been fighting an issue for HOURS and this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not subclass `UITAbleViewController` for this purpose. You are far better off with having a `UIContainterView` located at (0, 195, 320, 500) and a regular `UITableViewController` (or `AZControlViewController`, respectively that parts of `AZControlViewController` that control the talbe view) within. Its table view's frame would be (0,0,320,500).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. jmgarben.. you should define the frame in the viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad of the next view controller.It will work.

If you still have doubts.. you can ask.